# Google Maps' Custom Marker icon is not tappable (Using delegate)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-maps

I have implemented the `Google Maps` in my iOS app and to show User Location, I am using custom Marker Icon. Everything is working properly. I have implemented the `GMSMapViewDelegate`.

The issue is that the event `didTapAtCoordinate:` is not getting fired when I tap on the Marker Icon, but it does when I tap anywhere on the Map. Just the marker is not tappable while I have tried to set it `marker.tappable = YES;`

I have searched over the internet but couldn't get that what I am doing wrong or missing.

Below is the code:

```
/** SETUP MAP & MARKERS **/
-(void) setupMapMarkers {

    self.mapView.delegate = self;

    /** SET CAMERA POSITION ON MAP **/
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:[self.userObject.latitude doubleValue]
                                                            longitude:[self.userObject.longitude doubleValue]
                                                                 zoom:10];
    self.mapView.camera = camera;

    /** ADDING USER'S LOCATION MARKER **/
    CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([self.userObject.latitude doubleValue], [self.userObject.longitude doubleValue]);
    GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
    marker.tappable = YES;

    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"pin_user_active" withExtension:@"gif"];
    marker.icon = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
    marker.map = self.mapView;
}

#pragma mark - GMSMapViewDelegate

- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {

    NSLog(@"You tapped at %f,%f", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude);
}

// Added it just to check, if it works on tap
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapOverlay:(GMSOverlay *)overlay {
    NSLog(@"tapped");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through [GOOGLE MAPS COCOA DOCS](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/GoogleMaps/1.10.1/Classes/MarkerLayerViewController.html), got to know that there is another delegate method specifically for markers tap.

For delegate method

`- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate`

It states that:

> Called after a tap gesture at a particular coordinate, but only if a marker was not tapped. This is called before deselecting any currently selected marker (the implicit action for tapping on the map).

So for markers tap event we need:

```
- (BOOL)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker
```

I hope it will help others too.

Answer (score 1):

Give something to marker.title = @"some text" and call this delegate method:

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker;
```

When you click on the title, this method will be invoked.

Comment: Why do I need to give title, when the issue is with the marker tap. I have already mentioned that I am using delegate method and it is working for whole map but not the custom marker.